# Setting the background color of WPF TabControl inactive tabs

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Is there a simple way to set the background brush of all inactive tabs in a WPF TabControl? I want to emulate the look of VS 2010 on a TabControl--the background color  of the control's inactive tabs should match the background color of the window in which the TabControl is sited, so that you see only the text of the tab, and not the tab itself.

I know it will take a ControlTemplate to do it; I am trying to figure out what to put in the control template. Put another way, How do I specify that a particular brush should be applied to all inactive tabs? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Define the brushes, and then in your style for the tab, have a trigger for its active state, and when it is ACTIVE set it to one brush, and when the trigger fires because it is inactive set it to the other.

This can be done entirely in the XAML.

Comment: Thanks--I expanded on the answer below, but you get the checkmark for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution: As Stephen said, add a trigger to the control template. It's actually a property trigger, and it only needs to be set for the inactive state. So we set the trigger for *IsSelected = false*. We target the border (`Bd` in the default control template for a `TabItem`) of the `TabItem` and set its `Background` to the color we want (I use `RelativeSource FindAncestor` to match the grid on which the tab is placed). Then we set `Bd`'s `BorderThickness` to 0, and we're done:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0" />
</Trigger>
```

I put the trigger in the default template, just below the *IsSelected = true* trigger.

Note that the trigger is hard-coded to search for a `Grid` ancestor as the source of the inactive tab background color (`AncestorType={x:Type Grid}`). That's because I set my view background in the `Grid` that I use as my layout root. You will need to change the `AncestorType` if you use a different layout root control, or if you set your view background color elsewhere (such as in the `<Window>` tag).

BTW, you can also use the *IsSelected = true* trigger to change the `Background` of the active tab header from white, to match the `TabControl` background color:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}"/>
</Trigger>
```

For those who like this visual representation, here is the complete control template. It will be applied automatically to any `TabControl` within its scope. Simply add this markup to the  section of your XAML window (or import it from a `ResourceDictionary`), and your `TabControl` will get the VS 2010 look. Remember to change the `FindAncestor` proeprty so that the template will find the correct background color.

```
<!-- Styles for FS TabItem Control Template-->
<Style x:Key="TabItemFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="3,3,3,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabControlNormalBorderBrush" Color="#8C8E94"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItemHotBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#EAF6FD" Offset="0.15"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#D9F0FC" Offset=".5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#BEE6FD" Offset=".5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#A7D9F5" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemSelectedBackground" Color="#F9F9F9"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemHotBorderBrush" Color="#3C7FB1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemDisabledBackground" Color="#F4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemDisabledBorderBrush" Color="#FFC9C7BA"/>

<!-- FS TabItem Control Template-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TabItemFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabControlNormalBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemHotBackground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemHotBorderBrush}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Top"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,-1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-1,-2,-2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-1,-2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-2,-2,-2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemDisabledBackground}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemDisabledBorderBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```